# Rails PG::InvalidTextRepresentation - ERROR: invalid input syntax for type uuid

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, pg

We are migrating Rails application from MySql to Postgres. Generally, the application is loading fine.

I get the following issue if I try to update a record using `update_column`:

```
irb> parent.id
=> #<UUID:0x3fd2c1a61cf0 UUID:F2CABB99AAB84BEB8C64AD23AAC775C0>

irb> child.update_column(:parent_id, parent.id)
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation - ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type uuid: "--- !ruby/object:UUIDTools::UUID
time_low: 856850911
time_mid: 49931
time_hi_and_version: 17649
clock_seq_hi_and_reserved: 165
clock_seq_low: 247
nodes:
- 179
- 116
- 149
- 190
- 190
- 157
"
LINE 1: UPDATE "children" SET "parent_id" = '--- !ruby/ob...
                                                       ^
```

It's actually dumping the UUID YAML in resulting SQL instead of the string representation of UUID.

However, it works fine if I assign attribute and then save:

```
irb> child.parent_id = parent.id
irb> parent.save
=> true
```

Since we already have used `update_column` in many places in the application so we can't change it to assign and save.

`rails 4.2.7.1` `pg 0.21.0` `activeuuid 0.6.1`

Comment: Drop activeuuid gem (useless monkey patches).